# I want to add a variable in header location php mysql

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

```
header('location: {HERE THE VARIABLE}/admin/category.php');

header("location: {$hostname}/admin/category.php");
```

This is working but it keeps showing an error

> Cannot Imlicitly convert 'void' to 'string'

this error is showing

Code editor: VS code

Comment: This is not a PHP error. If you are asking about some message reported by some extension, you'd need to explain what extension it is. I also suggest you actually run the code and see if it actually works